# How to observe changes to an NSTextStorage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nstextstorage

I have an `NSTextStorage` delegate imlementing `textStorageDidProcessEditing:`. Unfortunately, the `userInfo` doesn't contain any details about the changes to the text.

How can I find out what actually changed?

Ideally I'd like to know everything sent to `[NSLayoutManager textStorage:edited:range:changeInLength:invalidatedRange:]`, but just the edited range would be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write your own subclass of NSLayoutManager and add it to your NSTextSTorage using `addLayoutManager:`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use KVO to observe the characters property of your NSTextStorage object (or any other property of it) and you get exactly what is changed in

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSTextStorage's getter methods editedRange and changeInLength.